# Access a javascript variable from a function inside a variable

Tags: javascript, scope

Hello i have the following issue i am not quite sure how to search for it:

```
function(){
    var sites;

    var controller = {
      list: function(){
        sites = "some value";
      }
    }
  }
```

So the question is how to access the sites variable from the top defined as

> var sites

EDIT:

Here is a more complete part. i am Using marionette.js. i don't want to define the variable attached to the Module (code below) variable but keep it private to the Module, hope that makes sense. Here is the code that works:

```
Admin.module("Site", function(Module, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _ ) {

  Module.sites = null;

  Module.Controller = {
    list: function (id) {
      Module.sites = App.request("site:entities");
    }
  };
});
```

and i would like instead of

> Module.sites=null;

to do

> var sites;

That sort of thing does make a difference right? Because in the first case i would be defining an accessible variable from outside where as the second case it would be a private one. i am a bit new to javascript so please try to make it simple.

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "access"?  Access it where? How? There's nothing wrong with what you've posted, but it doesn't do anything and it's not clear what you want it to do.

Comment: Yes as @Pointy mentioned, you need to mention explicitly what are you gonna do with it ?

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for global access, just declare the variable outside the function first, make your changes to the variable inside the function, then you can get the value whenever you need it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found some info on this: sadly what i am trying to do doesn't seem possible.

> [Can I access a private variable of a Marionette module in a second definition of that module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952491/can-i-access-a-private-variable-of-a-marionette-module-in-a-second-definition-of)

So i guess i have to do _variable to make developers know its private.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I have no experience using Marionette, however, what you're describing sounds very doable.

One of the most powerful (in my opinion) features of JavaScript is closures.  What this means is that any function declared from within another function has access to the variables declared in the outer function.

For example:

```
var func;
function foo() {
    var answer = 42;
    func = function () {
        // I have access to variable answer from in here.
        return answer++;
    };
}

// By calling foo(), I will assign the function func that has access "answer"
foo();

// Now I can call the func() function and it has access to the "answer"
// variable even though it was in a scope that doesn't exist anymore.
// Outputs:
// 42
// 43
console.log(func());
console.log(func());
```

What this means is that if you declare var sites from within your module definition function as you described, you should have access to it from within any of your inner anonymous functions.  The ***only*** exception is if Marionette is re-writing your functions (by using the [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) function and toString()), which seems unlikely but possible.

Your original example should would as described, my suspicion is that there is something else going wrong with the code that is unrelated to your scope.